# Editing the tag filter for the new nav is awkward

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, new-nav

When you go to edit the tags you want to filter on, they appear with the cursor at the end, and all of the tags 'off screen' (so to speak) and pushed to the left.

[image: Not all tags being shown for edit dialog]

Would it be possible for them all to be displayed as they were, just with `x` buttons to delete, and the input box above/below to add new ones? A little like the below (but with the delete button per tag):

[image: mock up of tag filter with separate input and existing tags]

Comment: @sklivvz Why has this been declined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While we do recognize that the way the current tag editor handles numerous tags can be improved, we have decided not to proceed with your solution. There are other areas that need work before this can be touched, and by the time we get there the problem might be better solved in other ways.

Comment: Would [tag:status-defered] work?

Comment: We're pretty sure it won't be done in this way. For example, one of the changes we are considering is ajaxing the whole page, which means losing the "apply" button as well...